# Testing whether my database connection is working with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, git, heroku

The app on Heroku was displaying the error `"We're sorry, but something went wrong"` up until I ran `heroku run rake db:migrate`, at which point the app didn't display any errors and worked fine besides not displaying any records from the database like it's supposed to.

I'm not sure whether the connection to the database on Heroku isn't working or whether the database on Heroku just has nothing in it, in which case I don't know why I can't push the contents on my local database to Heroku. `heroku db:push` didn't return any errors.

No errors from Rails or Heroku Toolbelt in the terminal, no errors on my local version, no errors on the version on Heroku, no indication of what isn't working.

Not sure what else to say.

This is what database.yml looks like:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: app_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: app_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: # heroku database
  username: # heroku username
  password: # heroku password
```

Update: I inserted a record into the database on Heroku manually and it threw up the "We're sorry, but something went wrong error". So I guess the connection isn't working.

Comment: Have you tried `heroku logs`?

Comment: Not until now, no. Everything appears to be fine up until it says "Starting process with command 'bundle exec rake db:migrate' and then 'Process exited with status 0'

Comment: He who readeth the logs findeth the error.

Comment: Sorry, I keep forgetting that enter submits the post. I updated it with some kind of lead, the full message is far too long to post.

Comment: exit status 0 means success.

Comment: Logs are fine like everything else then, I guess. Any other ideas?

Comment: Post the error message. People spent over 300 years wishing Fermat hadn't skimped on space - you don't have to repeat his mistakes.

Comment: try to use rails console in production using `RAILS_ENV=production rails console`, that will connect to heroku database and you can test several thing there.

Answer (score 1):

Push your local database to heroku using `heroku pg:push`.  For example:

```
heroku pg:push mylocaldb HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA --app sushi
```

Check issues with your Heroku postgres database with `heroku pg:diagnose`

See the [Heroku Postgres guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) for more information